# ¿Como crear un boton pausa start con react-countdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estuve buscando un modulo que me ayudara a hacer un cuenta atrás. Pero no encuentro como hacer un botón de start, stop. Levo mucho mas tiempo del que me gustaría buscando una alternativa.

```
import Countdown from 'react-countdown'

<Countdown
  date={Date.now() + 50000}
  intervalDelay={0}
  precision={3}
  autoStart={false} 
  renderer={props =>
    <h1>{props.total}</h1>
  }
/>
<p>{series[iSerie].coments}</p>
<div>
  <div>
    <button >pausa</button>
    <button >inicio</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import Countdown from "react-countdown";

export default function App() {
  const countdownRef = useRef();

  const handleStart = () => {
    countdownRef.current.start();
  };
  const handlePause = () => {
    countdownRef.current.pause();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Countdown
        ref={countdownRef}
        date={Date.now() + 50000}
        intervalDelay={0}
        precision={3}
        autoStart={false}
        renderer={props => <h1>{props.total}</h1>}
      />
      <button onClick={handlePause}>pausa</button>
      <button onClick={handleStart}>inicio</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Las respuestas que son solo código no son bien recibidas en el sitio. Por favor trata de [editar](/edit) la pregunta añadiendo una explicación de porqué el código que compartes puede solucionar la pregunta del OP.

Comment: La respuesta es correcta; aunque tiene más sentido `createRef` que `useRef` porque no nos interesa un `MutableRefObject` (no se va a sobreescribir la referencia). Sé que es evidente lo que hace tu código, pero toma en cuenta el comentario de @Lucía; a personas sin suficiente formación en React les ayudará saber qué estás haciendo y por qué. Saludos.

Comment: Muy interesante la diferenciación de useRef y createRef, pero de donde sacaron o definieron esos atributos ? Estuve escarbando en la documentación y usando el console log, pero nunca encontré una pista. Gracias. En efecto los comentarios son importantes.